# The cast to value type 'System.Boolean' failed because the materialized value is null

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, api

I know many people asked this question but I went through it all and nothing worked.

I have this simple web service:

```
public void View ([FromBody] int Id)
{
    using (var ent = new AEntities())
    {

        try
        {
            var result = ent.ViewApps.Where(p => p.AssignId == Id).OrderBy(x => x.Ack)
                         .ToList();

            HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
            HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";                       HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result));
            HttpContext.Current.Response.End();    
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { }     
    }
```

AppView

```
public partial class ViewApp
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public bool? IsPickedUp { get; set; }
    public string Mobile { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> AssignId { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> Ack { get; set; }
}
```

This is what I'm passing in postman: 15424

So I'm just passing a simple int in the body of the request.

The `AssignId` is of type `int` and can be null in the database.

Comment: Which line is this error on?

Comment: @andyb952 on this line : var result= ent.ViewApps.Where(p => p.AssignId == Id).OrderBy(x => x.Ack)
                         .ToList();

Comment: From the exception message looks like the problem is with some `bool` property of the `ViewApp` entity. You should get the same error even if you do simple `var result = ent.ViewApps.ToList();`, correct? Look at the entity `bool` properties (or post the entity class), one or more of them must be changed to nullable `bool?`.

Comment: @andyb952 x.Ack is of type int and it takes null so I want have the order with values before the null

Comment: @IvanStoev in ViewApps I have a bool variable I tried and set it to bool? And Nullable<bool> but still doesn't work

Comment: @mjwills Yes I have change bool to bool? , throws : The cast to value type 'System.Boolean' failed because the materialized value is null

Comment: @rav Revise your database columns and see if they are of the correct type as they are defined in your model class.